# MathJax rendering without \(.....\) 

Tags: latex, mathjax

I would like to know if I can use MathJax to render LaTeX notations without encapsulating a   \(....\) around LaTeX notations. For e.g. \frac{2}{3} instead of \(\frac{2}{3}\) and if so how do I go about setting it?

Many Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tex, but too old to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax needs some way to unambiguously delimit the mathematics on the page.  If you don't use `\(...\)`, then you have to use something else.  You can [configure MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/configuration.html) to use any string you want, but there does have to be something.  How would you expect MathJax to recognize `x+1` as mathematics for example, or just the variable `a`?  There needs to be some delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

i like to sorround the tex code with a pair of `$` as in `$\frac{2}{3}$` for inline math.